# Cannot see the rest of the card of the elements HTML 5

Tags: css, html, materialize

I cannot see the rest of the element of my form but in my inspector, the elements are there. I am using Materializecss for styling and using their card. Please see the image

[image]

Below is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col s8 offset-s2 valign">
    <div class="card blue-grey #ffebee red lighten-5">
      <div class="card-content white-text">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">

            <ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
              <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test-swipe-1">Login</a></li>
              <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-2">Register</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="test-swipe-1" class="col s12 white-text text-darken-2 #ff5252 red accent-2">
              <div class="sm-jumbotron center-align">
                <h5>Login</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--tab 1-->
            <div id="test-swipe-2" class="col s12 white-text text-darken-2 #ff1744 red accent-3">
              <div class="sm-jumbotron center-align">
                <h5>Register</h5>
              </div>
              <form class="col s12 white" #userRegistrationForm="ngForm">

                <div class="row">
                  <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input class="validate" type="text" name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.UserName" required minlength="3">
                    <label>Username</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="input-field col s6">
                    <input type="password" name="Password" #Password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.Password">
                    <label>Password</label>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                  <input type="text" name="Email" #Email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.Email">
                  <label>Email</label>
                </div>

              </form>
            </div>
            <!--tab 2-->
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
      </div>
      <!-- card-content -->
      <div class="card-action">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help please? Thank you.

Comment: Could you check whether they have applied fixed height property to the card element.

Comment: No they have none of that. In an example I have seen, it can go very long down.

Comment: I have tried to create the issue. But It's working fine in my end !. Could you disable the custom css and try again.

Comment: May I see your code please so I can try copying and pasting then modifying.

Comment: Can you please let me see your code so I may copy it and modify it to suit my needs?

Comment: I have used the exact same code u pasted above without using any custom css.

Comment: I don’t have custom css for that. My css is only for the input field for validation. Do you see everything like the jumbotron and the email input field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169077/discussion-between-praveen-murali-and-stack-questions).

Comment: Which browser are you using and which version? Seems to work fine in safari and chrome

Comment: I would like to continue it ina chat but I am not in front of my PC.

Comment: Even in the snippet, it is not showing everything.